# How do I determine which app is logging what line on logcat?

Tags: android, logcat, privacy

I want to check some very suspicious log lines I've seen on logcat, but I do not know to which app they belong. The log tag does not provide a hint.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by clicking on logcat and when the window from bottom opens, look for the dropdown saying no debugable process and by clicking it will show the apps running on your device then select one and see if the error is there in logcat. Plus you can also select "Show only selected application from same menu on right".

Comment: This does not work for other apps that are not mine, I'm talking about released apps on the Play Store.

Comment: buddy you cannot debug those.the apps that are on playstore are signed apk's.which cannot be debugged due to obvious reasons.please accept the answer if it was helpful.thanks

Comment: I do not want to debug those, I just want to get the package name so I can uninstall the offender. I am suspicious of an app sending location updates to a remote server, but I do not know which one.

Comment: if you want to get the package name.there is much simpler way.just open playstore on your desktop and search the app.then open the app and look in web url.At last you will see the package name of the app.After this word "details?id=" in url.please upvote the answer if this helps.thanks

Comment: You misunderstood. I need to get the package name that printed the line on logcat. I do not know which app or package name did it.

Comment: A commercially launched app, should it at all be allowed to send messages to logcat and noise down the system like that? I would suggest not.

Comment: hi carl,it cannot.commercially released apps don't allow you to debug them.They are signed apks.Which no one can debug.